# How to execute Javascript Functions on a server by Python script?

Tags: javascript, php, python

I have to execute some Javascript functions from a local machine without using a browser. Searching around the internet, I've found a solution.
This is my python code:

```
url = "http://url/to/my/php/script.php?variable=HelloWorld"
print("Url: ", url)

urlData = requests.get(url)
print(urlData.url)
```

And this is my PHP script:

```
<?php

$variable = $_GET['comune'];

    echo '<div id="map"></div>';
    echo '<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAXtpSi5amANeo6IcUuPuilyJMWcYc_RxY&libraries=geometry,places">
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../jsLibrary/geoxml3/kmz/geoxml3.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/popper.js@1.12.6/dist/umd/popper.js" integrity="sha384-fA23ZRQ3G/J53mElWqVJEGJzU0sTs+SvzG8fXVWP+kJQ1lwFAOkcUOysnlKJC33U" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-material-design@4.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap-material-design.js" integrity="sha384-CauSuKpEqAFajSpkdjv3z9t8E7RlpJ1UP0lKM/+NdtSarroVKu069AlsRPKkFBz9" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script>$(document).ready(function() { $("body").bootstrapMaterialDesign(); });</script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../jsLibrary/echarts.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../jsLibrary/charts_functions.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../jsLibrary/geo_visualization_functions.js"></script>';

    echo "<script>initMap();</script>";
    echo "<script>initZone('$variable');</script>";
    echo "<script>initSections('$variable')</script>";

    ?>
```

The idea is to generate an html code with php that automatically executes the javascript functions that I need. In fact, calling my php script within a browser all works fine! But if I try to call my php script, as I've done with my python script, anything works. What could be the problem? Is there another workaround?
My problem is executing those javascript functions from python, how can I do this?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Using Python to call PHP which returns JS... Why would anyone want to do this blows my mind.

Comment: I've a stack of python scripts to execute, after this execution I need to execute these javascript functions, but what I need is the automatically execution of this enormous stack of ibrid functions, because this ibrid stack should be executed on a server each two days for example, and I don't want execute each stack manually... I hope that my idea is clear :)

Comment: If the JS scripts are on the same machine as the python, then couldn't you use nodejs to run them? Calling node from python should work fine. Using a PHP server in-between is more than a little ridiculous.

Comment: No they aren't on the same machine. I know that is a really forced approach, but it's the first solution I found.